# How do you calculate the internal energy of a mixture of real gases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Is there an equation to calculate the internal energy of a gas mixture, or is it too complicated to be computed so simply? I know that there's $E_{internal}=N(degrees of freedom)\frac12kT$ and $(P+a\frac{n^2}{V^2})(V-nb)=nRT$, but are there any formulas for mixtures of real gases. I'm aware of the Wan der Waals equation, $a=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}(x_ix_j\sqrt{a_ia_i}), b=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}(x_ix_j\sqrt{b_ib_i})$, though I have no idea what it means or how to use it, so don't know whether or not it's what I'm looking for.

If this question is more appropriate for the physics stack exchange, feel free to move it.

Comment: You need to know their fugacity. Then multiply the molar ratio (or value depending on the units you need and information you have) of each real gas by its fugacity and internal energy and add those internal energies up to get the internal energy of the system.

Comment: Is the composition changing, or is it constant between the initial and final states?

Comment: @PulkitSharma How do you calculate the fugacity? The internet seems to suggest that you would need to know the fugacity coefficient (φ), but it also seems that the value of φ is dependent upon both the temperature and pressure. I feel like I'm way out of my depth with this.

Comment: @ChetMiller The variance in the composition is negligible and can be ignored.

Comment: https://www.eng.uc.edu/~beaucag/Classes/ChEThermoBeaucage/J.M.%20Smith,%20Hendrick%20Van%20Ness,%20Michael%20Abbott,%20Mark%20Swihart%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Chemical%20Engineering%20Thermodynamics-McGraw-Hill%20Education%20(2018).pdf

Comment: Read page 373 onwards. Fugacity and other reduced properties in a mixture is a real headache in itself I just don't want to get in again. I had to design a gas system once. Never again. I deal in liquids now. Even then electrolytes fuck me daily. I hate Dimethyl Acetamide.

Comment: @PulkitSharma Yeah, that's definitely way beyond me. It's giving me a headache already 'n' I'm not even close to understanding it yet. Thanks for the resource, though, I'll definitely work through it until I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

For an gas mixture of constant composition, you have  $$dU=C_vdT-\left(P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right)dV$$where U is the molar internal energy and V is the molar volume.  For a van Der Waals gas, you can show that $C_v$ is independent of volume, and is thus equal to the ideal gas heat capacity.